# Creating events with nested properties using INSERT INTO in Esper

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I have defined a XML-based event type `PositionUpdate` in Esper with nested properties as below.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="PositionUpdate.xsd"
targetNamespace="PositionUpdate.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="PositionUpdate">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
                        <!-- snip -->
            <xs:element name="currentLocation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="latitude" type="xs:double"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xs:element name="longitude" type="xs:double"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
                        <!-- snip -->
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now I want to use the INSERT INTO clause to create events of this type. However, I could not find a way to fill in the nested properties. The following EPL statement fails because of the dot (`currentLocation.latitude`).

```
INSERT INTO PositionUpdate
SELECT v2.latitude as currentLocation.latitude, v2.longitude as currentLocation.longitude
FROM PATTERN [ever v1=VehiclePosition -> v2=VehiclePosition(operatorId=v1.operatorId)
WHERE (v1.latitude!=v2.latitude OR v1.longitude!=v2.longitude)
```

The same syntax error occurs when I try `INSERT INTO PositionUpdate(currentLocation.latitude,  currentLocation.longitude) ...`

My question: Do you now of a way to fill nested properties using EPL statements?

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility to generate the schema XML document currently afaik. The easiest is to generate an object and marshal as XML.

Comment: The schema is generated manually and converted into a `com.espertech.esper.client.ConfigurationEventTypeXMLDOM` object. This part works, I can query the properties. What I want to do now is to set them with a EPL statement. The only way I found is to "flatten" the structure, i.e. having property currentLatitude, currentLongitude, previousLatitude and previousLongitude. However, I would like to use the nested properties.